# Terminating intermittently

Tags: windows, intermittent

Has anyone had and solved a problem where programs would terminate without any indication of why?  I encounter this problem about every 6 months and I can get it to stop by having me (the administrator) log-in then out of the machine.  After this things are back to normal for the next 6 months.  I've seen this on Windows XP and Windows 2000 machines.

I've looked in the Event Viewer and monitored API calls and I cannot see anything out of the ordinary.

UPDATE: On the Windows 2000 machine, Visual Basic 6 would terminate when loading a project.  On the Windows XP machine, IIS stopped working until I logged in then out.

UPDATE: Restarting the machine doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's not solved by you logging in, but by the user logging out.  It could be a memory leak and logging out closes the process, causing windows to reclaim the memory.  I assume programs indicated multiple applications, so it could be a shared dll that's causing the problem.  Is there any kind of similarities in the programs? .Net, VB6, Office, and so on, or is it everything on the computer?  You may be able to narrow it down to shared libraries.

During the 6 month "no error" time frame, is the system always on and logged in?  If that's the case, you may suggest the user periodically reboot, perhaps once a week, in order to reclaim leaked memory, or memory claimed by hanging programs that didn't close properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take this issue to the software developer.

Answer (score 0):

The more details you provide the more likely it will be that you will get an answer: explain what exact program was 'terminating'.  A termination is usually caused by an internal unhandled error, and not all programs check for them, and log them before quitting.  However I think you can install [Dr Watson](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6497291e-19e5-41a6-9192-68ec1da281df&displaylang=en), and it will give you at least a stack trace when a crash happens.